# How to return operation result in custom validator in soap web service at c#

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, wshttpbinding

I write one wcf soap web service with ws securtiy.I write custom validator .But I have problem.My custom validator only return; or send to throw exception.But I want to return operation result.I attached code below.How can I do?

```
  public class CustomValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {

            OperationResult retVal = new OperationResult()
            {
                ReturnCode = 0,
                ReturnMessage = "OK"
            };

            string s_userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"].ToString();
            string s_password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"].ToString();
            if (userName == null || password == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();--I dont want
                 return retVal; --It is good for me

            }

            if (userName == s_userName && password == s_password)
            {

                return;

            }
            else
            {

             //return;
               throw new FaultException("-2 Unauthorized");--I dont want this
               return retVal; --This giving problem.How can I solve?
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your validate method needs to return OperationResult  not void, that's your problem.

So the signature should be

```
public override OperationResult Validate(string userName, string password)
```

This means you'll need to update your UserNamePasswordValidator class as well to match this signature.

Comment: How did this solve your problem? According to [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.selectors.usernamepasswordvalidator?view=netframework-4.7.1), the `UserNamePasswordValidator` defines the method to return `void` not `OperationResult`. How can you override this?